# How does OpenID Connect communication work in the browser?

Tags: https, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

To connect to an Identity Provider(IDP) the Client has to build up a TLS Session for it.

- Is the browser only redirecting the communication of the client to the IDP or can the browser "read" the communication?
- So how does communication between the Client and IDP work?
- And how secure is the communication (client_ID, client_secret)? Can the browser see it?
- Do you have any sources of more information on communication between the Client and IDP?

I read the RFC but didn't find a complete explanation of communication with the browser.

Comment: Before i forget, do you have some sources for me where i can find the communication? I read the RFC but dosent find the complete explanation for the communication with the browser.

Comment: Minor edits for grammar. I hope you don't mind. Strange, I know. But it's all part of StackExchange's attempt to ensure quality questions (and answers!) Welcome to StackExchange. :-)